# How do i keep updating my web page whenever a user logs in into the website

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making a social networking site and I want to make a chatting system. So the page should automatically change the chat list when the chat column in the sql table updates.

Comment: Please provide any ideas, thoughts or code stubs that you have developed so far to show your commitment to actually learn something instead of making others do your work. Kind regards, Sebastian

Comment: with html5 - web-sockets, other - ajax

Comment: @sebastian link to my website-
http://www.yashwow.x10.mx/main/web.php
PLS DO NOT MIND THE ERRORS!!

Comment: i have not done any coding for the chat system

Comment: Its not possible, you can only check it periodically, theres no callback...

Comment: I suggest you something: do your development locally, and close what you already have online. Your html is invalid, but that might be ok so far. But your code is HIGHLY vulnerable, expecially to XSS. It has no control whatsoever on registration. Beware of what you put online, even if in testing!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to periodically update the page contents. See [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for examples.

Comment: yep ... ajax, & tha allmighty JSON ... right?

Comment: But be aware that this polling approach will result in much unwanted traffic when you update more often than new information is available.

Comment: but how do i do that??
i mean how do i use ajax to check when the table was updated??

Comment: @Yash Mathur send a request to a page to check for new items in the database, if there are any new entries update the page. Read the jQuery docs I linked to

Comment: @Nobody the trick is to check to see if any updates are required before updating any page contents.

Comment: @marto: That surely reduces traffic but I already meant it that way and http requests are expensive even if they are empty. Providing a udp network would be the most efficient but that is too much effort for this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a simple js recursion

```
function updateChat(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //update chat with ajax

        updateChat();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: what should the 'updateChat()' function look like??

Comment: 'updateChat()' calls himself every 5 seconds, before you call yourself you have to make an ajax call wich checks for new messages or something.